# android: using default video player

Tags: android, default, playback, android-videoview

I have an application that plays video files.

I have been using code for using `Videoview` and starting the `Videoview` manually to play video files. However, I just wanted to know if I can use the default media player or video player of android rather than creating or using the `VideoView` to play the file..

Please make comments if the question is not clear.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure - just use an `Intent` with the file `Uri`.

```
File file = new File("fileUri");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Sir, is it possible to provide a path rather than uri in a string? Moreover Sir, do you have any ideas about what other parameters can be passed like seekto etc? Your help will be appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: You need to pass the path of the file. You can do it like this: Uri.parse("filepath"). I don't believe it's possible to pass other parameters, sadly.

Comment: Sir, is there any other method because for some reason, the default video is unable to play the file.. I am not sure why.. Can you explain any other method.. Thanks

Comment: You can find all supported media formats in Android here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: Is it possible to start the video at a desired time? Can't find anywhere in the docs about this

Comment: There's no standard API for that. Some video players do support it with intent extras, though.